# Read a file from HDFS and assign the contents to string

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs

In Scala, How to read a file in `HDFS` and assign the contents to a variable. I know how to read a file and I am able to print it. But If I try assign the content to a string, It giving output as Unit(). Below is the codes I tried.

```
 val dfs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(config);
 val snapshot_file = "/path/to/file/test.txt"
val stream = dfs.open(new Path(snapshot_file))
 def readLines = Stream.cons(stream.readLine, Stream.continually( stream.readLine))
readLines.takeWhile(_ != null).foreach(line => println(line))
```

The above code printing the output properly. But If I tried assign the output to a string, I am getting correct output.

```
val snapshot_id = readLines.takeWhile(_ != null).foreach(line => println(line))
snapshot_id: Unit = ()
```

what is the correct way to assign the contents to a variable ?

Comment: You're using `println` which returns `Unit`. What is returned is stored in your variable `snapshot_id` which is `Unit ()`

Comment: @philantrovert Thanks for the info. Then what is the proper way to assign the contents to a string ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `mkString`. Since `println` returns `Unit()` which gets stored to your variable if you call `println` on you stream

```
val hdfs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(new java.net.URI("hdfs://namenode:port/"), new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration()) 
val path = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("/user/cloudera/file.txt")
val stream = hdfs.open(path)
def readLines = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(stream)
val snapshot_id : String = readLines.takeWhile(_ != null).mkString("\n")
```

Comment: readLines.takeWhile(_ != null).mkString is the file content

Answer (score 1):

I used `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString` to convert stream in to string

```
def getfileAsString( file: String): String = {
      import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
      val config: Configuration = new Configuration();
      config.set("fs.hdfs.impl", classOf[DistributedFileSystem].getName)
      config.set("fs.file.impl", classOf[LocalFileSystem].getName)
      val dfs = FileSystem.get(config)
      val filePath: FSDataInputStream = dfs.open(new Path(file))
      logInfo("file.available " + filePath.available)
      val outputxmlAsString: String = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(filePath, "UTF-8")
      outputxmlAsString
    }
```